# Docx (or doc) generation from jsp

Tags: java, jsp, apache-poi, docx, docx4j

First, sorry if my english isn't really good :s

I look for a solution to generate a word version of a jsp page. I tested many solutions but none seems to work correctly. The one who gave me the better result was to use the MIME for Word :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "">
<%@ page language="java" contentType="application/msword; charset=UTF-8" %>
```

But this solution works for IE only and forces the opening of the page in Word. But under the others browsers (chrome or firefox) it downloads me the code of my page in a .jsp

Another solution was to use POI, a Java API who I didn't success to set up.

Thanks in advance,

William

Answer (score 1):

Since you thought of using POI,I suggest you to use docx4j, follow this [link](http://java.dzone.com/articles/create-complex-word-docx) for setting up.

for importing docx4j library download latest docx4j.jar and add project build path or to  use the following dependency  for maven project

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.docx4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>docx4j</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.0</version>
</dependency>
```

use this code to convert your jsp to pdf

```
InputStream is = new FileInputStream(new File("your jsp file"));
WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage.load(is);
PdfSettings pdfSettings = new PdfSettings();
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File("your pdf file"));
PdfConversion converter = new org.docx4j.convert.out.pdf.viaXSLFO.Conversion(wordMLPackage);
converter.output(out, pdfSettings);
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: I've already try to use docx4j but I didn't success to set up it too :(

Comment: I am trying that. I placed the .jar in WEB-INF/lib but I suppose that I have to import the lib from my jsp?

Comment: What you are doing is generating a PDF from a jsp supposed to be in docx format. I really doubt it is what OP wants, even if docx4j is certainly a nice tool for generating a docx document.

Comment: At least if I can generate a PDF I will take that until I find a solution to have a docx :/

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing *generation* of a .doc and *transfert*. Apache POI or docx4j suggested by Naresh kumar are for the generation of a .doc or .docx file on the server. And the `contentType="application/msword; charset=UTF-8"` is for the transfert : it simply declares to the client that what follows should be a msword document.

*generate a word version of a jsp page* is hard to understand : jsp allows inclusion of dynamic elements in a textual document generally a HTML page, but it could be plain txt, or XML. But .doc or .docx are binary format that must be generated directly through a servlet using an appropriate tool.

You could also have a look to RTF format. It is (was ?) a textual representation of a msword document. As it is a text format, a JSP page could be used to include dynamic elements in a RTF page and then it would have sense to declare `contentType="application/rtf; charset=UTF-8"`.

According to the page on [wikipedia](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format), last version of RTF was published by microsoft in 2008, so you could also try to use [Open Document Format](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) or [Office Open XML](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML). Both format allow to generate a document via XML, but beware the final document is a zip file containing other xml files so it is still a binary format.

Comment: I suggested this approach only because @WilliamN used POI.

Comment: In fact, It doesn't matter to me how is created the doc since I can save and modify it. The simpliest way will be the best :) I will take a look to the RTF and Open XML format

Comment: @WilliamN : IMHO you should first generate and save a docx file server side in a servlet via docx4j or Apache POI, and then output it directly from the servlet. No need for a JSP.

Comment: https://github.com/plutext/docx4j-ImportXHTML/ converts XHTML to docx content, so perhaps you could create a custom JSP tag which uses that,  and wrap it around the rest of your JSP content?